# Human-readable date formats

Tags: c#, .net, date, user-experience, timespan

You may have noticed that certain web applications (for example, certain parts of GMail) display dates in a more human-readable format than simply DD/MM/YYYY.

For example, if I open up a mail item from the 23rd (which happens to be 3 days ago at the time of writing, I'll get the following:

> Dec 23 (3 days ago)

I'd like to implement similar logic to this in my own web application.

For example, when dealing with a .NET TimeSpan object, I'd like to convert it to text such as the following:

> 2 months
>
> 3 days

Is there a .NET library capable of doing this already?

If not I might build something basic and open-source it.

---

I've made a basic start here:

```
public static class TimeSpanHelpers
{
    public static string ToHumanReadableString(
        this TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        if (timeSpan.TotalDays > 30)
            return (timeSpan.TotalDays / 30) + " month(s)";

        if (timeSpan.TotalDays > 7)
            return (timeSpan.TotalDays / 7) + " week(s)";

        return (timeSpan.TotalDays) + " day(s)";
    }
}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time

Comment: I've got a simple algorithm for that on my blog that you could extend: http://www.robfe.com/2009/09/timeago-for-csharp/ Not very different to yours I'm afraid...

Comment: Awesome... I knew someone would be asking this but couldn't figure out what terms to type into the search box.

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time There you'll find several C# implementations for relative time (i.e. "5 mins ago", "10 days ago").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Noda Time](http://groups.google.com/group/noda-time) group is in the process of doing just this. Come on over and join the fun. Forgot to mention the project location [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) project

Comment: Cool stuff! I'll head over there.

Comment: Looks cool. Can you give us an idea where in the Node Time project we should look.

Comment: Have you done it? It's been almost 10 years since :)

Answer (score 14):

Try Humanizer http://humanizr.net/

```
TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1299630020).Humanize(3) => "2 weeks, 1 day, 1 hour"

// in de-DE culture
TimeSpan.FromDays(1).Humanize() => "Ein Tag"
TimeSpan.FromDays(2).Humanize() => "2 Tage"

// in sk-SK culture
TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1).Humanize() => "1 milisekunda"

// and a lot more
DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2).Humanize() => "2 hours from now"
"case".ToQuantity(5) => "5 cases"
"man".ToQuantity(2) => "2 men"
122.ToWords() => "one hundred and twenty-two"
(.5).Gigabytes().Humanize() => "512 MB"
"Long text to truncate".Truncate(10) => "Long text…",
"Sentence casing".Transform(To.TitleCase) => "Sentence Casing"
```

Nuget:

```
Install-Package Humanizer
```

Answer (score 1):

Another library for doing this: http://relativetime.codeplex.com/

(Available on NuGet)

Comment: It works okay, but can't seem to do future dates (eg, I want it to say "in 2 days")

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/628203/74585) as I needed to support future dates like 3 days from now.